# django foreignkey accessing through related_name

Tags: django

From what i have read and from a few posts on here (and reading their solutions) I thought I had implemented this correct.  It would appear that I have not quite grasped something with foreign keys and related_name.  Here are my models and what I am trying to do in order to access the linked class.

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    menu_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name="Menu Name")
    urlconf_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name="URLConf Name")
    menu_position = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Menu Position", unique=True)
    has_sub_menu = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Sub Menu Linked")
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Menu Active")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.menu_name

class Sub_Menu(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['menu_position']
    sub_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name="Sub Menu Name")
    urlconf_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name="Sub Menu URLConf Name")
    menu_position = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Sub Menu Position")
    menu_id = models.ForeignKey(Menu, related_name="submenu")
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Menu Active")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sub_name
```

Now I thought I could simply access the linked data using something.submenu (i.e. the related_name) but it doesnt seem to work.  With the above code, I've tried;

```
the_menu = Menu.objects.filter(urlconf_name=split_path[0])
built_breadcrumb.append([the_menu[0].menu_name, split_path[0]])
if the_menu[0].has_sub_menu:
    built_breadcrumb.append([the_menu[0].submenu.sub_name, the_menu[0].submenu.urlconf_name])
```

That doesnt work.  I've just realised that it will return a list of items but I'm still struggling to work out how to access them.  I've also tried;

```
the_menu[0].submenu.filter(urlconf_name='home/contactus')
```

This also errors.

I'm racking my brain so I someone could explain how to access through the related_name I'd really appreciate it.  I've done this (through help with someone on here) but it doesn't seem to work in this context for some reason.

Thanks very much in advance.

Wayne

Comment: Rather than saying "this also errors", you should read the error you get and see if you can understand what it's telling you, and if not post that actual error message here.

Comment: Fair comment.  The errors are confusing me more because I think I'm not quite grasping the concept around it.  (Pdb) the_menu
[<Menu: The Club>] - Shows the initial query works.  (Pdb) the_menu[0].submenu
<django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager object at 0x039FEFB0> - Shows its referencing something through the related_name.  (Pdb) the_menu[0].submenu[0].sub_name
*** TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object does not support indexing - I'm clearly not grasping someting.  I though it'd return a list of one to many sub_menu entries.

Comment: No, it returns a Manager. You have to call manager methods like `.all()` or `.filter()` on it.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel-Roseman, one of the books I've been ready mentioned a Manager, will have to find it again and re-read that.  Thanks, its made a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Primary problem

Facts (as read from your models):

- A menu can relate to many submenus.
- A submenu can relate to one menu

With this in mind, read again this line:

```
built_breadcrumb.append([the_menu[0].submenu.sub_name, the_menu[0].submenu.urlconf_name])
```

This part in specific:

```
the_menu[0].submenu.sub_name
```

`submenu` is a queryset, so you need to handle it as such. In other words: "get `sub_name` of WHICH submenu?"

#### Additional problem

`.filter` returns a queryset, `.get` returns one object, so you probably want something like this:

```
the_menu = Menu.objects.get(urlconf_name=split_path[0])
```

Now `the_menu` contains a reference to one menu, so you can loose the `[0]` after it in the subsequent lines.

#### Secondary problem (not really, but is misleading as hell)

Don't call your field `menu_id`, here:

```
class Sub_Menu(models.Model):
    ....
    menu_id = models.ForeignKey(Menu, ...)
```

Here is why:

```
the_menu = submenu.menu_id 
# the_menu is now an instance of a Menu class, not an ID

the_menu_id = submenu.menu_id.id  # the_menu_id is now an ID (integer)
# or:
the_menu_id = submenu.menu_id_id  # the_menu_id is now an ID (integer)
```

I'm proposing there is a less confusing way to name your fields:

```
class Sub_Menu(models.Model):
    ....
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, ...)
```

Now the same example as above:

```
the_menu = submenu.menu 
# the_menu is now an instance of a Menu class, not an ID

the_menu_id = submenu.menu.id  # the_menu_id is now an ID (integer)
# or:
the_menu_id = submenu.menu_id  # the_menu_id is now an ID (integer)
```

It makes sense to ask for `.menu` and get a `Menu`.
It makes less sense to ask for `.menu_id` and get a `Menu`.

The thing is that Django internally creates a field to hold the ID of the foreign key and names it by adding "_id" to the field name, hence `menu_id_id` in the first example and `menu_id` in the second example.

Additional side-note (assuming the updated field name):

`the_menu.menu.id` raises `SubMenu.DoesNotExist`, while `the_menu.menu_id` simply returns `None`. Just something to keep an eye on, if ever using `menu_id` directly.

Again, this is assuming the changed field name. The same holds if not, just add an `_id`.

#### Ok, let's rework the lot...

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    ...

class Sub_Menu(models.Model):
    sub_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name="Sub Menu Name")
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, related_name="submenus")
    ...
```

Note the changes:

1. `menu`, not `menu_id`
2. `submenus`, not `submenu`

Ok, now names match that what they actually reference.

```
try:
    the_menu = Menu.objects.get(urlconf_name=split_path[0])
except Menu.DoesNotExist:
    # what to do if menu does not exist?
    return # or raise or something...
built_breadcrumb.append([the_menu.menu_name, split_path[0]])
if the_menu.has_sub_menu:  # this line is now probably not needed, just remove it and go straight to the for loop (of course, un-indent the for loop)
    for submenu in the_menu.submenus.filter(active=True):  # I added .filter(active... But if wanna go over all the submenus regardless of 'active', then use .all() instead of .filter(...)
        built_breadcrumb.append([submenu.sub_name, submenu.urlconf_name])
```

This should get you to the right track.

#### Oh wait, are you looking to a 1-to-1 relationship?

While writing my answer, it occurred to me that you might want to have a one-to-one relationship between Menu and SubMenu classes. If that is the case, then `ForeignKey` is the wrong tool for the task. Instead you should check out [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#ref-onetoone). Here is how that would work:

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    ...

class Sub_Menu(models.Model):
    sub_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name="Sub Menu Name")
    menu = models.OneToOneField(Menu, related_name="submenu")
    ...


try:
    the_menu = Menu.objects.get(urlconf_name=split_path[0])
except Menu.DoesNotExist:
    # what to do if menu does not exist?
    return # or raise or something...
built_breadcrumb.append([the_menu.menu_name, split_path[0]])
try:
    built_breadcrumb.append([the_menu.submenu.sub_name, the_menu.submenu.urlconf_name])
except SubMenu.DoesNotExist:
    # what to do it there is no submenu
    pass  # probably nothing, just move on
```

#### Final note

In any case, I think you don't need the `has_sub_menu` field, because you can get that info from the other fields. For 1-to-1 relationship it is shown above with try-except blocks. And for 1-to-many (i.e. foreign key) relationship, the `for` loop simply won't do anything. Or if you really need, you can use `.count`like this:

```
if the_menu.submenus.count() > 0:
    ....
```

Though keep in mind that this is an additional hit on the database, and is probably not necessary (and as such it should be discouraged).

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to reply.  Its really good of you to explain like you have, it'll help me learn.  I've not programmed since my uni days back in the early 90's, been learning Django for a few months and Python for around 5 months so still new.  Will try the code tomorrow when i get chance.  Good shout with the .get btw, cannot beleieve i missed that.  Not sure I understand what the advantage of changing the menu_id ? Sure that'll be something I'll twig at some point.  I'm sure i tried to loop it prior to posting (nice touch with the .filter btw).  You were correct, 1tomany

Comment: Your a star @frnhr.  Some of that has just fallen into place now.  A couple of other bits I'll go and re-read to affirm my knowledge.  I've 3 books on Django now, the first one I got around 100 pages in and after fixing a few issues with the examples i reach a bit in the book that was just completely wrong, then I realised it was from 2009 so bought a new one, lol.  Thanks again for taking the time to produce such an extensive response.  Wayne